# Replace repeated letters in a word with exception

Tags: java, regex

I would like to have a regex expression that (in java) will replace every repeated consonant into single letter, all repeated consonants but an initial "inn".
I explain myself better with some examples:

`asso > aso`

`assso > aso`

`assocco > asoco`

`innasso > innaso`

I found a way to replace all repeated letters with

`Pattern.compile("([^aeiou])+\1").matcher(text).replaceAll("$1")`

I found a way to recognize if a word does not start with "inn":

`Pattern.compile("^(?!inn).+").matcher(text).matches()`

but I don't know how to merge them, ie, degeminate all geminates consonants but the initial 'nn' if the word starts with 'inn'.

Anyone can help me? (I would like to solve this with a regex, in order to apply `replaceAll`)

Thank you

Comment: `inninnasso` would result in `inninaso`?

Comment: @Mauro If I am not mistaken, the selected answer will result in `innasso > inaso` Is that the expected? https://ideone.com/U0hekY

Comment: Testing with java code, the answer of rzwitserloot seems correct. But that of The fourth bird requires less steps.

Comment: The first rule of using regular expressions is:  You don’t have to do it all in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to capture a word that starts with `inn` using a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` in group 1, and capture  matching `[^aeiou]` in group 2 and repeat the backreference to that group 1 or more times.

```
(?<!\S)(inn)|([^aeiou\r\n])\2+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(inn)` Capture group 1, match `inn`

  - `|` Or
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[^aeiou\r\n]` Match any char except the listed
- `)\2+` Close group and repeat 1+ times what was captured in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yi2cxF/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/U0hekY)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1$2`

For example

```
final String regex = "(?<!\\S)(inn)|([^aeiou\\r\\n])\\2+";
final String string = "asso\n"
     + "assso\n"
     + "assocco\n"
     + "innasso";
final String subst = "$1$2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
aso
aso
asoco
innaso
```

Comment: Your solution requires 159 steps, while rzwitserloot's 235, so your's the fastest. Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly, the ```(?<!\S)``` serves the purpose to match those ```inn``` inside a word.

Comment: The negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` makes sure that what is on the left is non a non whitespace char, so what is on the left should be a whitespace char or the start of the string. This part `(?<=^)(inn)` will match inn when what is on the left is the start of the string.
This part `(?<!\S)(inn)` will match inn what what is on the left is not a whitespace char or the start of the string.See https://regex101.com/r/9LeAPb/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/rUbtJa/1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you must do this all with a single regexp, but if you must... try using negative lookbehind:

```
Pattern.compile("((?<!^i(?=nn))[^aeiou])+\\1")
```

This gobbledygook broken down:

- `(?=X)` means: Don't consume anything, just check if X occurs here. If not, it's not a match.
- `(?<!X)` means 'negative lookbehind': It doesn't consume any characters, but it fails to match if X occurs at this exact spot. So, if at this exact spot we're on the first character in the text, *and* it is an 'i', then it's a failure no matter what.
- `(?<!^i(?=nn))` does not consume anything, but it fails for any position where the following holds: Immediately before the 'cursor' there is an i, and before that, the start of the string. After the 'cursor' there are 2 n's. If that all holds, fail. Otherwise do nothing (continue processing).
- The rest is then just what you wrote already.

Comment: Thank you! It's because this regexp should go in a properties files, and should not be some part of code.